# Cannot invoke 'UIView.init' with an argument list of type '(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)'

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My code for this is:

```
import UIKit

class RCSubscriptionPackageView: UIView {

let centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout = CenteredCollectionViewFlowLayout()
let collectionView :UICollectionView
let cellPerWidth = 0.7

let container: UIView!

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    collectionView = UICollectionView(centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout: centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout)
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Error is in the above initializer

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

    centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(
        width: self.bounds.width * CGFloat(cellPerWidth),
        height: self.bounds.height * CGFloat(cellPerWidth) * CGFloat(cellPerWidth)
    )
    centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true

    addContainerView()
    addConstraintsForContainer()
    collectionView.register(
        RCSubscriptionPackCollectionViewCell.self,
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: RCSubscriptionPackCollectionViewCell.self)
    )


    centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true



}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addContainerView() -> Void {

    container.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    container.addSubview(collectionView)

}

func addConstraintsForContainer() -> Void {
    container.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
}


}
```

the error says 'Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass'

and in

```
 super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
```

error is
'Cannot invoke 'UIView.init' with an argument list of type '(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)'

I have searched about it every where but didn't got anything.
Please get me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` supports these two initializers

- `init(frame: CGRect)`
- `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

`init(nibName:bundle:` belongs to a view **controller** or a NIB